# Field not found, JRXML has definitions?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using *iReport Designer 5.5.0*, and was making a test *JRXML*. I added a text field with a value of $F{pricing_date} and added "pricing_date" to the list of "fields" on the Report Inspector panel (no properties or description set for the field).

The resulting JRXML has the "pricing_date" field defined:

`<field name="pricing_date" class="java.lang.String"/>`

And it has a text field with $F{pricing_date} as expected:

`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pricing_date}]]></textFieldExpression>`

But... I get  the error "Field not found : pricing_date" within *iReport*, and I get the same error during compilation.

I've compared this to other *JRXML* files within the samples provided, and it seems to match... what am I missing? Is there a setting somewhere to recognize field definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two possible reasons here.

1. If the report does not compile, the problem might be that the element in which you have placed the textField uses a different datasource than the one in which you have declared the field.
2. If it does not run, you might be missing the field in the object type of the datasource. Also, if you use JRBeanCollectionDataSource from java you have to have the getter for your field (declared as `getPricing_date(){...}`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, sure enough, I had the field defined at the root level of the report, which I guess doesn't carry through to the individual table datasets!